# How to distribute a multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I would like to create a modular app that takes the following folder structure:

Sample directory structure:

```
main dir/---mainApp.jar
        /---plugins ---/module1.jar
                       /module2.jar
                       /etc.jar
                       /etc_etc.jar
```

However, using maven, each module takes its own directory structure from the project root:

```
mvnmodularapp/mainApp/
             /pom
mvnmodularapp/module1/
             /src
             /target/module1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
mvnmodularapp/module12
             /src
             /target/module2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Is there a way that I can structure it in such a way that a user will only have to download the a `mainApp.jar` and then later on have the option of downloading more modules into a plugins folder adjacent to mainApp.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to determine a custom build artifact.